# Another Cocoa: Crash in _NSDisplayOperationStack; Need Guidance too

Tags: cocoa, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

Much like the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818419/cocoa-crash-in-nsdisplayoperationstack-need-guidance), I too have problems with the NSDisplayOperationStack.
Let me make the context clear first though.

I have a window which contains a `view`, in there a `tabView` with several buttons, textviews and labels. The `view` inside of the `tabview` originates from a different NIB, which uses Auto Layout (as all of the views, buttons etc. do) and has constraints set up.

The constraints are made in IB excluding a single constraint being made in the WindowController. This constraint attaches the `view` of the `tabView` to it's superview with a visual constraint in the form of `@"H:|[viewInsideTheTabView]|` and `@"V:|[viewInsideTheTabView]|`. Next to that constraint, no constraints are being made or added programmatically.

With this context, I run and test my app only to see the following error appear after resizing the window several times.

The error:

**`*** Assertion failure in -[_NSDisplayOperationStack exitDisplayOperationForWindow:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1138.51/AppKit.subproj/NSDisplayOperationStack.m:343
Exception _NSDisplayOperationStack underflow raised during heart beat. Ignoring....`**

When this exception is raised, the app freezes and does not become responsive again. I already checked every single button, view etc. for concurrent drawing, but none are (at least that is what IB tells me).

Is there anyone who encountered the same error and knows how to respond to it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14649260/674648) within the tread you're referring to, it might be of use... My problems  also only occurred in OSX 10.7, not OSX 10.8.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the same app (and resizing several times) on OSX 10.8 and it never crashes. It seems to me that Apple fixed a lot of (including this one) constraint problems on 10.8.

This makes it looks, to me at least, that 10.7 is like a test-case for their constraints. And to add some grounds for that comment; most of the methods used for animating constraints are available on 10.8 and later.

Still; if someone can counter this answer, please do!